# How to check whether the image is blur or not in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am developing an app where i capture picture through mobile camera. Before displaying the picture it should check whether it is blur or not. Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: What have you tried and/or found yourself? I don't think there is an instant solution, but working with [OpenCV](https://pub.dev/packages/opencv) might work with [this article as a guideline](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/).

Comment: Opencv package is available in flutter. Using this we can convert the  normal image to blur image. But i am not sure how to use laplacian in flutter. This is the place where i am struggling.